# Merging two tables with common foreign key which is the primary key of the third table into a single row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following three tables.

table 1: `mymaster`

```
id     name       age
--------------------
123    fiesta     0
124    figo       0 
125    classic    0
```

table 2: `mychild1`

```
id   mymaster_id   item   itemvalue   date_time
----------------------------------------------
 1    123         classic   800000      null
 2    125         classic   800000      null
 5    123         fiesta    1100000     null
```

table 3 : `mychild2`

```
id   mymaster_id  item  itemvalue date_time
-------------------------------------------
1    123          dzire  800000     null
2    124          sx4    100000     null
3    123          dzire  500000     null
```

`mymaster_id` is the foreign key for `mychild1` and `mychild2` tables which is the primary key of `mymaster` table. This is the output table that I want.

```
mymaster_id  id   item   itemvalue   date_time   id   item   itemvalue  date_time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123        1  classic   800000      null       1    dzire   800000     null
  123        5  fiesta    110000      null       3    dxire   500000     null
  124        null null    null        null       2    sx4    100000      null
  125        2  classic   800000      null       null null    null       null
```

I tried using a few queries(like the one below) but its not giving me the output table that I need.

```
select mm.id,mm.name,mc1.item,mc1.itemvalue,mc2.item,mc2.itemvalue  
 from mymaster mm 
  left join mychild1 mc1 on mc1.mymaster_id=mm.id
  left join mychild2 mc2 on mc2.mymaster_id=mm.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `GROUP BY` in your `SELECT` query

```
GROUP BY mm.mymaster_id
```

You query will look like

```
select mm.id,mm.name,mc1.item,mc1.itemvalue,mc2.item,mc2.itemvalue 
FROM mymaster mm 
LEFT JOIN mychild1 mc1 ON mc1.mymaster_id=mm.id 
LEFT JOIN mychild2 mc2 on mc2.mymaster_id=mm.id
GROUP BY mm.mymaster_id;
```

Comment: Sorry, seems I put my output table wrongly. Just edited the output table.

Answer (score 0):

or just:
`SELECT mm.id,mm.name,mc1.item,mc1.itemvalue,mc2.item,mc2.itemvalue

FROM mymaster mm

WHERE mc1.mymaster_id=mm.id AND mc2.mymaster_id=mm.id`

Comment: Sorry, seems I put my output table wrongly. Just edited the output table.